# what is the expansion for $\log \sum q^{n^2}$?

Tags: power-series, special-functions, theta-functions, q-series

what is the expansion for $\log \sum q^{n^2}$ ?

---

Using the Jacobi triple product 
$$ (q;q)_\infty(z;q)_\infty (q/z ;q)_\infty = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} z^k q^{\binom{k}{2}} $$
if we set $q \to q^2$ and $z \to q$
$$ (q^2;q^2)_\infty(q;q^2)_\infty (q ;q^2)_\infty = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{n^2} \tag{1}$$ 
quite confusingly [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_theta_function) has
$$ (q^2;q^2)_\infty(-q;q^2)_\infty (-q ;q^2)_\infty = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{n^2} \tag{2}$$

---

In one paper I found: 
$$\theta(x; q) = (x;q)_\infty (qx^{-1}; q)_\infty = \exp \left( - \sum_{ m \neq 0} \frac{x^m}{m(1-q^m)} \right) \tag{$\ast$} $$
however there is a factor of $(q;q)$ missing. Then if we plug in $x = q^2$ and $ p = q$:
$$\theta(q; q^2) = (q^2 ; q^2)(q;q^2)_\infty (q; q^2)_\infty = \exp \left( - \sum_{ m \neq 0} \frac{q^{2m}}{m(1-q^{m})} \right) $$
We we expand out the [Pocchammer symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol):
$$  \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{n^2} = 
\prod (1 - q^{2m+1})^2(1 - q^{2m})$$
Then I might take the log of both sides and get my answer:
$$
 \log \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{n^2} = 
\sum \Big[2\log (1 - q^{2m+1}) + \log(1 - q^{2m})\Big]$$

Then recall the formula for $\log$
$$ \log (1 -x ) = \sum \frac{x^m}{m}$$

Comment: Your application of the Jacobi triple product formula needs minus signs before $z$ on the left-hand side. The correction achieves consistency with $(2)$.

Comment: Also take care about where to start with $m$.

Comment: Dear @cactus, could you provide the title of the paper that you mentioned in your post. I'm curious to know in what context they considered such an identity.